# Будет ли функция многопоточной, если она вызывается внутри многопоточной функции? Python, threading

Tags: python, многопоточность

Пример:

```
def foo():
  bar()
def bar():
  print("Hello world")
for i in range (ThreadCount):
  thread = threading.Thread(target=foo)
```

Будет ли bar исполняться несколькими потоками, или ее исполнение переходит в основной поток?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Исполняются ли вызовы функции во многих потоках или нет никак не зависит от самой функции—захотите она в одном потоке будет исполняться, захотите ещё 10 потоков добавите, каждый из которых вызывает вашу функцию.

Функции не исполняются несколькими потоками, если вы не отправите их явно на исполнение в несколько потоков.

`target=foo` говорит, что после старта потока (если добавите `thread.start()` вызов в ваш код), `foo()` будет в нём выполняться. `foo()` в свою очередь может создать новые потоки или отправить какую-нибудь функцию на исполнение в другой поток—функции в Питоне можно передавать в качестве аргументов в другие функции (как `target=foo` явно демонстрирует).

В вашем случае `bar()` просто вызывается в `foo()` поэтому естественно `bar()` будет исполняться в том же потоке что и `foo()`. Если вы запустите `foo()` в основном потоке, то `bar()` будет исполняться в основном потоке.

Answer (score 0):

да, каждый тред начется с выполнения foo(), и все последующие вызовы будут выполняться в том же [псевдо]потоке

Comment: *"[псевдо]"* тут ни чему. Потоки в Питоне реализованы поверх потоков ОСи.

Comment: @jfs gil так не считает

Comment: Даже не смешно сколько раз я видел, как элементарные ошибки типа: `target=f()` объяснялись "экспертами" наличием GIL в CPython. Наличие GIL не делает потоки менее реальными и не имеет никакого отношения к текущему вопросу.

Comment: @jfs оукей, блокирующие друг друга треды.